# Receiving forwarded emails via SendGrid

Tags: asp.net-mvc, sendgrid

I want to use SendGrid to receive emails. Here is my scenario.

User A will send an email from `user-a@example.com` to User B at `user-b@example.org`

I've setup a rule so that emails received by User B are forwarded to `c@example.net`.

`example.net` is my domain and I have configured `example.net` in SendGrid to point to an MVC controller which will process the JSON posted by SendGrid.

Is this possible? I was able to receive one email but after that it stopped working. What went wrong? Can any one help me out?

Comment: SendGrid has the ability to receive and inbound emails with [the Inbound Parse Webhook](https://sendgrid.com/docs/API_Reference/Webhooks/parse.html).   _However, to answer your question, we need to know more._ What language are your using? What's your environment? What have you tried? What are the steps you've taken?

Answer (score 0):

The problem was solved via a different channel. The resolution can be found here: https://community.sendgrid.com/sendgrid/topics/receiving_forwarded_mails_send_grid

Through using a number of debug tools, including [RequestBin](http://reaquestb.in) and [Runscope](https://runscope.com), the user found there was an error in their controller, rather than an error in forwarding or message parsing.

> We were able to debug and find the problem which as you predicted was with our controller. 
>   We are still testing by sending mails from various domains but have not come across any mail that is getting lost.
>   — [saurabh abhyankar](https://community.sendgrid.com/people/saurabh_abhyankar), [May 22nd 10:53 AM GMT](https://community.sendgrid.com/sendgrid/topics/receiving_forwarded_mails_send_grid)